# Yii 1.1 Use two database connection at same time

Tags: php, yii

I want to use to database connection at the same time. I got two servers having same database. I want to update both the database at the same time i.e On the add/update/delete on my app both the database needs to up updated accordingly. I have added the following in the main.php

```
        'db2'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbanme',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
        'enableProfiling'=>true,
        'enableParamLogging'=>true,
        'class' => 'CDbConnection',
        ),
```

And then in my controller in the Add action :

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
       $model=new TestTransaction;

       if(isset($_POST['TestTransaction']))
       {
            $originalDbConnection   = Yii::app()->db;
            $latin1DbConnection     = Yii::app()->db2;
            $model->attributes      = $_POST['TestTransaction'];
            if($model->save()) {
                Yii::app()->setComponent("db",$latin1DbConnection);
                $model->save();
                Yii::app()->setComponent("db",$originalDbConnection);
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));    
            }
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

But this is not working. Please help me out.

Comment: Why on earth wold you want to do this. Why not just do something more robust like database replication

Comment: try this - http://yii.at/ehwM15X  & http://yii.at/JaUjsSR

Answer (score 0):

It's because AR model cache DB object.

```
public function getDbConnection()
{
    if(self::$db!==null)
        return self::$db;
    else
    {
        self::$db=Yii::app()->getDb();
        if(self::$db instanceof CDbConnection)
            return self::$db;
        else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }
}
```

You may manualy set model $db attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set third parameter of [setComponent](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#setComponent-detail) to false:

```
if($model->save()) {
    Yii::app()->setComponent("db",$latin1DbConnection, false); // set third parameter to false
    $model->save();
    Yii::app()->setComponent("db",$originalDbConnection, false);
    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));    
}
```

this disable merging new component with old one.

Thanks.